# why is cygwin seeing older versions of the same files?

Tags: cygwin

I was hoping to use Cygwin to "tail -f" an apache log file on one of my Windows machines. So in my cygwin terminal, I cd over to the log directory, and I get:

```
ccurvey@MINNIE1 /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs
$ ls -l
total 21
-rwx------+ 1 ccurvey        Domain Users  6004 Feb 25  2012 access.log
-rwx------+ 1 ccurvey        Domain Users 39519 Feb 25  2012 error.log
-rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users     6 Jul 17 23:48 httpd.pid
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM        6104 Feb 25  2012 install.log
-rwx------+ 1 ????????       Domain Users     0 Feb 24  2012 minnie.log
```

But if I look at the same directory in a DOS command window, I see:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs>dir
 Volume in drive C is Minnie OS
 Volume Serial Number is 9C28-B005

 Directory of c:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs

07/17/2013  11:48 PM    <DIR>          .
07/17/2013  11:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/17/2013  11:48 PM        10,514,794 access.log
07/17/2013  11:48 PM         2,458,745 error.log
07/17/2013  11:48 PM                 6 httpd.pid
02/25/2012  01:04 PM             6,104 install.log
02/24/2012  10:56 AM                 0 minnie.log
           5 File(s)     12,979,649 bytes
           2 Dir(s)   1,897,603,072 bytes free
```

So why is my DOS window showing me that access.log was last modified on 7/17/13, and my cygwin terminal tells me the same file was last modified on 2/25/12?  (I did look, and the contents of the files are different!  You can see the file size differences right on the listings.)

======

UPDATE:  I ended up uninstalling my existing version of cygwin and installing a brand-new copy, and everything is working now.

Comment: Just tested, couldn't reproduce -- I think the question is invalid/too  localized. Can you please test this manually? Open a file in Notepad and `tail -f` that file in cygwin and modify the file in Notepad, saving often, and update results.

Answer (score 1):

Use an updated version of cygwin. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked other directory also.

If same error is there also then I suggest to use any updated version of `cygwin`. May be that is the problem.